# Github - Link prior commits with wrong email adress to Github account

Tags: git, github, commit, author

I had the wrong email adress configured in my git (`git config --global user.email`) and made some commits and pushes.

Now these commits are not linked to my Github account.

Is it possible to link them to my account afterwards?
I already tried to add the "wrong" email adress to my Github profile but that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

not possible, unless u are ready to have force push (rewrite those same delta changes as new commits)